# One Ui 6 QuickTime port for S10 one ui 5.1 rom

Tags: android, user-interface, apk, porting, samsung

Hi im currently working on Porting the New Quick and New Media Player of one ui 6 to S10 one ui 5.1 rom Ivan xda

To install via magisk

I have got both SystemUi.apk

And have Decompile both to a folder

Now I have a question what I have to do now to port it

I want to SystemUI/res/layout

And there were a buch of qs.xml

Files (QuickSettings is the qs)

Now I my Probleme is

Do I have to copy all the QS.xml
Files and replace them in the s10 oneui5.1 SystemUi/res/layout folder replace them with the new from One Ui 6

Is the port the done or is there somthing I have to do still with both folders

Im new to Porting SystemUi mods

If anyone know would be nice

If anyone can help me with that would be nice